# How to print the input and output of a function for testing

Tags: c, unit-testing, testing, printing

I want to test functions that I have already created and want to print to a.out the input and output of the function like the examples below

sample function

```
int check_len(int color, int destination, int origin, int len){}
```

sample output/print

```
check_len(GREEN, 3, 6, 4): VALID
```

Comment: To do this across an entire project, you would need to adopt a workflow that creates a wrapper function for every function in the project. Whether you call the function directly, or through the wrapper, would be controlled by a `#define`. The wrapper would call the function, and then print the output. It's a lot of extra work to pretty print arguments as strings, e.g. `GREEN` instead of the raw integer value.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could do it with plain `printf()` and maybe a dedicated function that would convert the color number to a string. There are test libraries too, like [google test](https://github.com/google/googletest), that you can use.

```
const char *colors[] = {"GREEN", "BLUE", "YELLOW", "RED"};

const char *get_color(int color_index)
{
   int size = sizeof(colors) / sizeof(colors[0]);

   if (color_index >= size)
   {
      /* handle out of bounds error */
   }

   return colors[color_index];
}


void test(int color, int dest, int org, int len)
{

   int retv = check_len(color, dest, org, len);
   /* lets assume 0 if for green */
   printf("check_len(%s, %d, %d, %d): %s\n", get_color(color), dest, org, len, retv == 1 ? "VALID" : "INVALID");
}
```

Here, a conditional expression is used to check whether the returned value is what you asked for, in this case, if you wanted **1** as the return value of `check_len`, *"VALID"* is printed else *"INVALID"*.